# Out Of Memory happened when there is lots of free memory

Tags: linux, out-of-memory

I got the OOM problem randomly, but it seems that there is enough free memory.

```
storage_worker invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x34200ca, order=0, oom_score_adj=0

Normal free:35064kB

Normal: 2194*4kB (UH) 1393*8kB (UH) 574*16kB (UH) 115*32kB (UH) 22*64kB (UH) 1*128kB (H) 1*256kB (U) 1*512kB (U) 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB
```

There is 35064KB free Normal memory, it is enough to alloc one page.

I can not understand the reason and how to resolve it ....

**Linux kernel version:**
4.4.94

**dmesg:**

```
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.803][32391.180952] storage_worker invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x34200ca, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.803][32391.189969] CPU: 0 PID: 997 Comm: storage_worker Tainted: G           O    4.4.94 #1
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.803][32391.198125] Stack : 80637a02 00000048 00000000 80640000 00000000 00000000 800751d4 805ca5e7
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.804]          80544390 00000000 000003e5 80634728 00000565 00000000 805f47e0 800751c8
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.804]          805f47e0 801edae0 00000000 00000000 80549900 83831aa4 83831a88 800a6304
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.804]          00000000 800349ec 80637a02 0000004f 83831aa4 ffff00fe 00000000 831e49c0
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.804]          00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.804]          ...
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.805][32391.235533] Call Trace:
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.805][32391.238116] PC:[<8001fad4>], Position:show_stack+0x70/0x8c
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.805][32391.243881] PC:[<801e33c4>], Position:dump_stack+0x94/0xd0
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.805][32391.249637] PC:[<800daff4>], Position:dump_header.isra.5+0x54/0x184
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.806][32391.256233] PC:[<800ab284>], Position:check_panic_on_oom+0x48/0x8c
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.806][32391.262719] PC:[<800ab3e4>], Position:out_of_memory+0x11c/0x314
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.806][32391.273592] PC:[<800af66c>], Position:__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x714/0x75c
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.806][32391.280639] PC:[<800a7c8c>], Position:pagecache_get_page+0x1d0/0x264
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.807][32391.287309] PC:[<800a7fa0>], Position:grab_cache_page_write_begin+0x28/0x48
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.807][32391.294653] PC:[<8010f948>], Position:block_write_begin+0x2c/0x98
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.807][32391.301064] PC:[<8010fc58>], Position:cont_write_begin+0x2a4/0x460
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.807][32391.304230] queued_list is NULL, done_list = 2
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.807][32391.312231] PC:[<c0236470>], Position:exfat_write_begin+0x6c/0xb4 [exfat]
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.808][32391.319375] PC:[<800a7764>], Position:generic_perform_write+0xe8/0x1f0
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.809][32391.326235] PC:[<800a96e0>], Position:__generic_file_write_iter+0x1c8/0x1f8
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.809][32391.333551] PC:[<800a99a0>], Position:generic_file_write_iter+0x290/0x298
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.809][32391.340694] PC:[<800dd7a8>], Position:__vfs_write+0xc8/0xec
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.810][32391.351200] PC:[<800ddec8>], Position:vfs_write+0xb4/0xfc
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.810][32391.356877] PC:[<800de5bc>], Position:SyS_write+0x58/0xb4
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.810][32391.362545] PC:[<80024eb8>], Position:syscall_common+0x30/0x54
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.811][32391.368653] 
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.811][32391.375737] Mem-Info:
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.811][32391.381350] active_anon:4389 inactive_anon:43 isolated_anon:0
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.812][32391.381350]  active_file:14 inactive_file:18 isolated_file:0
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.812][32391.381350]  unevictable:0 dirty:3 writeback:0 unstable:0
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.812][32391.381350]  slab_reclaimable:445 slab_unreclaimable:1625
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.813][32391.381350]  mapped:2 shmem:148 pagetables:121 bounce:0
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.813][32391.381350]  free:8696 free_pcp:15 free_cma:0
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.814][32391.431195] Normal free:35064kB min:1088kB low:1360kB high:1632kB active_anon:17556kB inactive_anon:172kB active_file:56kB inactive_file:72kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:81920kB managed:74400kB mlocked:0kB dirty:12kB writeback:0kB mapped:8kB shmem:592kB slab_reclaimable:1500kB slab_unreclaimable:6500kB kernel_stack:1208kB pagetables:484kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:64kB local_pcp:64kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:768 all_unreclaimable? yes
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.816][32391.482043] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.816][32391.485605] Normal: 2194*4kB (UH) 1393*8kB (UH) 574*16kB (UH) 115*32kB (UH) 22*64kB (UH) 1*128kB (H) 1*256kB (U) 1*512kB (U) 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB 0*8192kB 0*16384kB 0*32768kB 0*65536kB = 35088kB
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.818][32391.509280] 188 total pagecache pages
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.818][32391.513172] 20480 pages RAM
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.818][32391.516116] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.818][32391.520227] 1880 pages reserved
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.818][32391.523550] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.819][32391.532525] [  669]     0   669      508       74       5       0        0             0 system_call
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.819][32391.542252] [  757]     0   757   149782     4032      90       0        0             0 camera
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.904][32391.556200] [  760]     0   760      457       17       3       0        0             0 procd_program
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.904][32391.566076] [  771]     0   771      454       13       4       0        0             0 telnetd
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.904][32391.575424] [ 2767]     0  2767      458       19       3       0        0             0 sh
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.905][32391.589119] [14391]     0 14391      457       18       3       0        0             0 udhcpc
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.905][32391.598384] [14420]     0 14420      649       77       4       0        0             0 wpa_supplicant
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.906][32391.608405] [15032]     0 15032      453       11       3       0        0             0 sleep
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.906][32391.617699] [15050]     0 15050      453       11       3       0        0             0 sleep
[2023-06-21_01:44:18.913][32391.631536] Kernel panic - not syncing: Out of memory: compulsory panic_on_oom is enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you think the OS can alloc one page, but you don't know how many page is allocating in that moment, and you don't know is the free memory is contiguous or there is a lot of fragmentation and so the page cannot be allocated. About 35MB of free space in modern system are really low memory free space.
So is typical that the system raise this type of errors.
Probably also the swap memory is full, and so the system go OOM.

Comment: This is embedded system that only has 80MB total memory. The free memory is managed by buddy system that works by dividing memory into blocks of a fixed size, with each block being a power of two in size. the mininum size of memory block is a page, so it is not caused by fragmentation.

Comment: Ok, so IDK what can cause this